# Exception: Service unavailable: Documents Error in Google Doc Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

I have an odd issue with a Google Doc Apps Script.  It's been working for months without any issues.  Then yesterday I get the Error Message:  "**Exception: Service unavailable: Documents**" whenever I try to position an image blob (either from a URL Fetch or from getFileById).  I simplified my code to this, and no matter what image I use, I always get the error.

```
function debugProc () {
  var rLlogoborderlessId = '1ZhOX_aneaAhM0XJV4oQHGfNPUzaVETgu';
  doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
  curBody = doc.getBody();
  var addlines = curBody.appendParagraph('');
  var imgpara = curBody.appendParagraph("");
  imgpara.setAlignment(DocumentApp.HorizontalAlignment.CENTER);
  var logoimage = DriveApp.getFileById(rLlogoborderlessId).getBlob();
  var addlineslogo = curBody.appendParagraph('');
  var k2nplogo = addlineslogo.addPositionedImage(logoimage);
  // Error:  Exception: Service unavailable: Documents
}
```

I tried multiple different computers and browsers.  Nothing works.  No workaround that I can find.  How can I resolve this?

Comment: It might be a problem on the Google side... checkout the Google Apps Script issue tracker to see if there is a related report, if not, report it there (ref. https://developers.google.com/apps-script/support).

Comment: OP's report at the tracker: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/240007207

Comment: Tried a new document?

Comment: I tried a new doc and it worked.  I can't figure out why my old Google Doc is corrupted or blocked.  I didn't want to make a new doc (there are several formatting requirements that make "a new doc" not an easy workaround), but I'm stuck.

Comment: Hi there @NicholasPisca! In order to replicate this problem, could you please share a copy of the Doc that generates the error? Please remember to delete any private information therein.

Comment: Jacques, thanks for following up.  The weird thing is, if I put the code in a new google doc module, it works fine.  The old Google Doc is the only place where the code malfunctions.

Answer (score 0):

By reading your new comments I understand that the case isn't reproducible on new documents. The issue may have originated from a problem with your project or a bad configuration. To fix it, you only need to create a new Doc and copy all the data there. Feel free to leave a comment below if you need help with the migration.

Comment: That's not really a fix. I mentioned your workaround in my bug request, because it's not ideal to just scrap the original google doc. Lots of factors play into a Google Doc, & it's not just as easy as Copy+Paste the text into a new page. This particular doc had extensions installed to allow custom formatting, it was shared across several users, it had the aforementioned apps scripts attached (with HTMLs), & most importantly, it's callback was saved with other sites for API calls. In the end, I did make a new doc, but it would be nice to know why the original failed, to avoid that in the future